# Unable to map json response to Object because of multiple implementations

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

I have this class structure:

ResponseBody.java:

```
public class ResponseBody {
    private String type;
    private A a;

    public static class A {
        private List<B> b;
    }
}
```

B.java:

```
public class B {
    private String c;
    private DynamicJson dynamicJson;
}
```

DynamicJson.java:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
      include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child1.class, name = "child-1"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child2.class, name = "child-2"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child3.class, name = "child-3")
})
public abstract class DynamicJson {
    private String onlyKnownField;
}
```

Child1.java

```
@JsonTypeName("child-1")
public class Child1 extends DynamicJson {

// Number of fields and field names here change based on which implementation of Dynamic Json

}
```

Likewise, Child2 and Child3 classes.

Removed constructors, setters, getters.

I want to cast/deserialize below json to `ResponseBody.java` class.

```json
{
    "type": "child-1",
    "a": {
        "b": [
            {
                "c": "guid",
                "dynamicJson": {
                    "onlyKnownField": "guid", // only field that always comes
                    /*
                    dynamic number of fields based on "type", say 2 fields, if type is                                                                         
                    something else then number of fields here is different
                    */
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The field "dynamicJson" can have different number of fields with different names inside it based on "type" value. Which seems to be the problem,

This is the code being used:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
ResponseBody responseBody = objectMapper.readValue(json.getBody(), ResponseBody.class);
```

However, above code give this error:

```
Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class DynamicJson]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Let me know if other info is needed.

Comment: "type" property should be the property of the DynamicJson's subclass.

Comment: @SergeyVasnev Neither of DynamicJson's subclasses have a type/key that can identify them 
 separately from each other. What other option do I have?

Comment: As an option, you could look at JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY mechanism.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check